# How do I create a link to add a new entity form from the referenced entity

Tags: theming, entities

I've created an entity (using [Entity Construction Kit](https://drupal.org/project/eck)) that has an entity reference field referencing a node. I would like to create a link on that node to create a new entity. I want to do this on the node template file. I have looked into sandbox module [Prepopulate Create Node Links](https://drupal.org/sandbox/hazah/1488826) but I'd rather just code it.

Answer (score 1):

The [entity_connect](https://drupal.org/project/entityconnect) module will do that for you.

Comment: In my use case Node Type B has a reference field to Node Type A .... I'm trying to get a link on Node A to create a new Node B (that pre populates Node A in the field reference). Seems like that module is designed to do it the other way around.